# Rewrite instead of redirect with Azure Web App/Linux

Tags: apache-2.4, azure, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure rewrite rules with `.htaccess` on an Azure Web App with Linux+Apache(+PHP), however I can only get redirects to work (but no rewrites).

The source is structured as following:

```
./.htaccess
./updates/
./updates/.htaccess
./updates/check/
./updates/check/api.php
./updates/certificates/
./updates/certificates/api.php
./... # other files - must not be downloadable
```

My `./.htaccess` is:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^updates/([A-Za-z]+)" "/updates/$1/api.php" [L,QSA]
```

EDIT: The problem also persists with

```
RewriteRule "^updates/([A-Za-z]+)$" "/updates/$1/api.php" [L,QSA]
```

My `./updates/.htaccess` is:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

What I need, is to have an internal rewrite, that rewrites `/updates/check?foo=bar` to `/updates/check/api.php?foo=bar` and `/updates/certificates?a=b&c=d` to `/updates/certificates/api.php?a=b&c=d`.

What I get is a HTTP 301 Redirect to `http://$server/updates/check/?foo=bar`. When I add `R=301` (or `R=302`) to the rule flags, I get an 301 (or 302) redirect to `http://$server/updates/check/api.php?foo=bar`. Note the `http` in both cases (I make an request to https with curl) and the entirely wrong rewrite in the first case.

I'm not sure if the client can handle redirects. This is why I'm trying to do an internal rewrite.

What do I have to do to get that rewrite working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I get is a HTTP 301 Redirect to `http://$server/updates/check/?foo=bar`

Yes, because `check` is a physical subdirectory so mod_dir will (by default) "fix" the URL by appending a trailing slash to the URL-path via a 301 external redirect. This is necessary for mod_dir to be able to serve the `DirectoryIndex` (if you have one).

If you changed your URLs to include the trailing slash then you wouldn't have this problem.

You can avoid this redirect by disabling the `DirectorySlash`. If you do this you *must* ensure that directory indexes (mod_autoindex) are disabled to prevent accidental discloser of your filesystem.

For example, at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
```

This also means that any other directories are not going to be directly accessible without manually appending the trailing slash with an internal rewrite (or external redirect) - although that may or may not be an issue for you.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

---

**UPDATE:** Because of this "restriction" I would be inclined to change the file (or URL) structure to avoid such conflicts, rather than disabling `DirectorySlash`.

For example:

```
/updates/check-api.php
/updates/certificates-api.php
```

And rewrite accordingly:

```
RewriteRule ^updates/([A-Za-z]+)$ /updates/$1-api.php [L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> order deny,allow
> deny from all
> ```

Note that these are Apache 2.2 directives and are formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4. You should be using `Require all denied` and `Require all granted` instead. However, you should avoid mixing both old/new auth directives since you can get unexpected results (one does not necessarily override the other).

Comment: Thanks so much, the rewrite now works!

I wanted to ask a follow up question about the `order` directive, but I missed that they are commented out in Azures `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf` so I guess it should be safe to use only `Require` directives.

Comment: You're welcome. TBH I would probably choose to change the file (or URL) structure to avoid such "conflicts" to begin with, rather than disabling the `DirectorySlash`. I've updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: I need to use TLS client auth on one of the endpoints (but not on the other one). Azure has a configuration to exclude specific paths from the client auth, but I'm not sure if its applied to the URL or to the file system. I can test that at some point.

I have now tried to access various combinations with and without `/` with curl, and got a 403, so I think I should be good with `Require all denied` in `/` and `Require all granted` in `/updates`. The server doesn't host anything else.

Comment: To clarify, first I had a `.htaccess` in one of the "API subdirectories" that enabled the client auth and provided the path to the CA, thus the single `api.php` file per directory. However, client auth can't be enabled this way in Azure but must be done via the configuration page of the service.